# What does this UDP Packet mean?

Tags: networking, tcpip, wireshark, protocol, udp

I'm total newbie at tcp/ip and I was experimenting with Wireshark.

What this mean:

```
1824    578.194204  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy UDP Source port: 17500  Destination port: 17500
```

In data I can see that my user pc name is sent (happily it's a generic name): does this mean someone is trying to hack my pc ?

Update I have another one which is port 56712 and yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy is the ip of someone with the same provider as me. Isn't this weird (OK I'm paranoïd :)) ?

Comment: You watched too many movies. :P

Comment: Maybe you're right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use Dropbox or similar software?  Apparently the port you listed is used by Dropbox...

http://isc.sans.org/port.html?port=17500

Edit:  Looks like it could be someone elses machine with Dropbox installed looking for "Lansync Compatible clients"  http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=16253

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that DropBox had this peer-to-peer sync capability

Comment: Dropbox do that :) @rupello: me too

Comment: Yes It's probably my Dropbox !

Comment: But what about port 56712 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do have dropbox this link shows how to turn that off if that is what you want

[DropBox Forum](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=16253)